# Produce and Consume data in Java RESTful with Jersey and JSON

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

Folks,
I am newbie to Java RESTful,

I need to pass the data from my java application to the RESTful service. I am able to add the RESTful to my application but not able to send any data back to the service.

I used @GET and @Consumes at service. Please help me to get connect and data exchange between the same

As RESTful acts as server in my application

RESTful defined

```
@GET
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("{strID}")
public String getJson(@PathParam("strID")String strID){
  return strID;
}
```

Imported RESTful method

```
public String getJson(String strID) throws UniformInterfaceException {
        WebResource resource = webResource;
        resource = resource.path(java.text.MessageFormat.format("{0}", new Object[]{strID}));
        return resource.get(String.class);
    }
```

inside the java application

```
static RESTful objRFIDService = new RESTful();
objRFIDService.getJson("RESTfultest");
```

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Sharing a bit of code will help us to help you.

Comment: Take a look at this url : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/restful/index.htm may be help you to better understand restful and please like Vladimir and Cassio said share some code.

Comment: Which entity will your webservice return?

Comment: Yeah. I edited the post. Sorry, Just misunderstanding posted in comment. @esprittn I gone through that tutorial and implementing same here.

Comment: No, I need to send to webservice, not anything back from webservice

Comment: Yes, alphanumeric value to webservice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve is not really clear. However, to consume a REST webservice, you can use the JAX-RS Client API, which is part of the [JAX-RS 2.0](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) specification and the reference implementation is [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/).

For instance, to perform a `GET` request to a resource available in `http://example.com/api/foo/{id}`, you can use the following code:

```java
String id = ...

Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target("http://example.com").path("api").path("foo").path(id);
String result = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE).get(String.class);
```

For more details, have a look at the [Jersey Client API documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/client.html).

Comment: Thanks Cássio Mazzochi Molin. I will check

Comment: I tried with 
http://www.bhaveshthaker.com/13/introduction-developing-implementing-restful-web-services-in-java/
tutorial and working fine. But when I accessed in my java client, it causing exception POST http://localhost:8050/WebRestfulAppTest/services/WebTest/add returned a response status of 500 Internal Server Error, could not able to communicate with the server. Please help

Comment: @PrajwalBhat Could you please consider asking another question? If so, I'll be glad to help you. This error seems to be out of the scope of this question. Ensure you provide all the details such as error messages and stacktraces in the new question.